# Recursive sequence addition Python

Tags: python, recursion, for-loop

I am a bit stuck.

I am trying to calculate the distance to move gears of different sizes so they align next to each other. I think its some sort of recursive call, but I can't figure out how to write it. 
I have a list of radii in the order of the gears

radiusList=[6,16,14,20,24,28]

so the 1st gear = movement distance = 0 
2nd gear movement distance = 0 + 6 + 16 
3rd gear=0 +6 + 16 +16 + 14 
4th gear = 0 +6 + 16 + 16 + 14 + 14 + 20 
5th gear =  0 +6 + 16 + 16 + 14 + 14 + 20, +20 ,+ 24 
6th gear = 0 +6 + 16 + 16 + 14 + 14 + 20, +20 ,+ 24 + 24 +28 etc... 
 
The other thing is I need it to update - now matter on the radius size, and the number of gears. But can't get my head around how to approach it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE : Thanks everyone, I wrote something like this in the end. Sees a bit long winded though.

```
def createmovesequence():
if numberofcogs == 0 :
    void
if numberofcogs == 1:
    newmovelist.append(0)
if numberofcogs == 2:
    newmovelist.append(0)
    newmovelist.append(radiusList[0])
    newmovelist.append(radiusList[1])
if numberofcogs >= 3:
    newmovelist.append(0)
    newmovelist.append(radiusList[0])
    #newmovelist.append(radiusList[1])
    for i in range(2, len(radiusList)):
        newmovelist.append(radiusList[i-1])
        newmovelist.append(radiusList[i-1])
    newmovelist.append(radiusList[-1])
```

# elif numberofcogs != len(radiusList):
     #   print 'error'
        print newmovelist

## createmovesequence()

My only other idea was something along the lines of a for loop with lot of if statements...

Answer (score 0):

```
def dist(n, radiusList):
  if n <= 1:
    return 0
  return dist(n-1, radiusList) + radiusList[n-1] + radiusList[n-2]
```

Comment: Second call to dist should take 2 parameters. It's giving the wrong answer anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Here's a solution without recursion:

```
>>> gears = [6,16,14,20,24,28] 

>>> def distance(n, radius):
...    return sum(gears[:n] + gears[1:n-1])

>>> distance(1, gears) == 6
True

>>> distance(2, gears) == 6 + 16
True

>>> distance(3, gears) == 6 + 16 + 16 + 14
True

>>> distance(4, gears) == 6 + 16 + 16 + 14 + 14 + 20
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop you probably wanted to see is:

```
gear = 4    # which gear
total = 0   # distance. we start from zero

# for each idx such that 0 <= idx < gear…
for idx in xrange(gear):
    total += radiusList[idx]
    total += radiusList[idx+1]
```

Note how the loop does nothing in case `gear = 0` (because there's no such number that would be smaller than zero and yet at least equal to zero). This is probably the most explicit notation, but hcalves' one is shorter and learning it will be helpful for you too.